# Naming convention for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this might be a silly question, but I need to create a new page.

I currently have a controller called jobs, that let's you create a job. However what I want is for there to be a step 2 of the part of creating a job.

Should I create a new controller, and create an index page there, or should I create a page say called part2.html.erb and in the controller create the def part2?

Which leads me into the question is it okay to create names for pages that are not index, show, new, edit and if you need a new page like that create a new controller for it. Or would it be ok to call it things like part2 f.ex. What's the best practice?

Comment: I personally think that, having names like `part2` etc will soon lead to a mess. Try giving something meaning full name like `job_detail` or anything that represents what you try to do..

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine for you to define controller actions however you like. It's just in your best interest to follow CRUD (create, read, update, delete) 95% of the time.

Personally, I have a fallback in my routes file which sends any "unknown" request to the Pages controller. EG..

```
# routes.rb
match ':action', :via => :get, :controller => 'pages'
```

This would work for `mysite.com/privacy-policy`, `mysite.com/contact-us`.. whatever

With regards to creating a multi-page form, check this out
http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms